# Get the data from Child Component to Parent Component

Tags: angular

I have a question regarding the rendering of dynamic component. I have a `Parent component` and a `Child component`. In `child component template` there are text fields and the user can enter values. In there, I also have a submit button, the function of submit button is declared in the `Parent Component`.

My problem now is when I clicked the submit button, I can't get the values that the user entered in `Child Component Template`. I have to get the latest data from `child` to `parent`. I really don't have an idea on how to solve this I've seen `@output` but still reading tutorial about it. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: You can define Reactive form and pass it as @Input to child component, then on submit you will have all data in parent component. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically the child component will output/emit an event with the data and parent component will subscribe/listen to the event (basically a Pub/Sub model). This can be achieved through `EventEmitter` in Angular2. Please refer to this [link](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2) also this [one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html).